# Prove that the problem of factoring α is in NP

Tags: computation-theory, np

Trying to brush up on computation theory but am not sure of solution to this:

```
Prove that the problem of factoring α is in NP.
```

I have a feeling it may be related to finding an NP problem and finding a reduction to the problem of factoring α.

Comment: Try http://math.stackexchange.com/ - this isn't really programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple actually.  Multiplication is in P.  NP is the same as "checking all possible polynomial sized solutions in parallel".  If alpha is encoded as a length n bitstring, the factors total length is at most n + c.

What it is not is "NP-complete".  There is no way to turn an arbitrary NP problem into factoring.

Comment: I'm really not sure what else to add.  I'd just end up saying the same thing slower.  Go look at any one of the definitions for "NP", and they all come down to being able to verify a solution in P.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem in P** : is a problem, that is computable by Deterministic Turing Machine in polynomial time
**Problem in NP** : is a problem, thas is polynomicaly veryfiable by Deterministic Turing Machine.

In NP, we are using non-determinism in such way, that we require only one branch of a computation tree to be accepted (we try "all" possibilities at the "same" time). Polynomicaly veryfiable means, that we have a certificate (let it be c), that is a solution to the input word (let it be w). Certificate must be of a polynomial length considering input length. Our task is only to verify if a certificate is a solution. For example in SAT(satisfyability problem) a certificate is a correct assignement (which is guessed non-deterministically).

So You prove that your problem is in NP : 
There exists a DTM that verifies a pair (w,c), where w is input number and c are its factors. You must just construct a veryfier that multiplies factors in c and compares it to w.